# Pandas to_json date format is changing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date-format, to-json

I have this dataframe with **start_date** and **end_date**

[image]

and when i convert to json using **to_json** using this line

```
json_data = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

now if i print **json_data** the start_date is getting converted from **yyyy-mm-dd** to **integer** format

Please suggest a way so that the date format remains in **yyyy-mm-dd** format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set the format of your date, then set the `date_format` to `'iso'`:

```
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
data = df.to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso')
print(data)

[{"start_date":"2020-08-10","end_date":"2020-08-16"}]
```

Comment: hey, i tried this but there is extra content in the date like `T00:00:00.000Z` ... how can i remove this? I want the final output as `[{"start_date":"2020-08-10","end_date":"2020-08-16"}]
`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for datetime columns, convert to format `YYYy-MM-DD` and last overwrite original data by [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes('datetime').apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
```

Then your solution working correct:

```
json_data  = df.to_json(orient='records')
```